# What to say in ceremonies, incidents and some situations in French ?

Tags: expressions

I wanted to know what to say in ceremonies and some situations in French, (I will list some, and make update whenever I face/remember a situation):

1. when someone is sick: how to show his/her support? to ask if thinks get better ? to wish healing ....
2. when someone wants to go to/return from the gym
3. someone gets maried/divorce
4. someone gives birth
5. what to say when someone died
6. someone sneezed
7. when someone will move to another place (last day in a job/neighborhood/city...)

Comment: Case 2 (going to/return to the gym) is a bit unclear: what do you want to say ? Something like "enjoy !" ? Same for case 3: what is the idea or feeling youwant to convey for a divorce ?

Comment: You mentioned that you will "make update whenever I face/remember a situation". Please *don't* do that, especially since the question has been answered. You're asking too many questions on a single question.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some common phrases for such situations (there are a lot of variants for them):

Case 1:

> Je vous souhaite un prompt rétablissement (formal)
>
> Remets-toi vite (less formal)
>
> Soigne-toi bien/Soignez-vous bien
>
> Prends soin de toi/prenez soin de vous

Case 3 (some phrases you would use for a wedding - I can't think of an equivalent for a divorce):

> Tous mes voeux de bonheur
>
> Félicitations !

Case 4:

> Félicitations !
>
> Toutes mes félicitations aux parents
>
> Félicitations pour l'heureux événement

Case 5:

> Toutes mes condoléances (formal)
>
> Mes sincères condoléances (formal)
>
> Reçois toute mon affection/ma sympathie (more friendly)
>
> Je suis désolé d'apprendre cette nouvelle

Case 6:

> À tes/vos souhaits!

Case 7: I can't think of a common phrase for this situation. Depending on the relation you have with the person who leaves, you could say:

> Donne-nous de tes nouvelles
>
> Gardons le contact
>
> Bonne chance à ton nouveau poste
>
> Bonne continuation

Comment: thank you for responsing, for (1) it i correct to say to someone tha was sick and and he has just returned ....: t'as bien rétabli ?? if not(or yes) what to say (is there other form )

Comment: In an informal, friendly setting, you can say eg *tu vas mieux ? Tu t'es bien rétabli ? Tu t'es bien remis* ? (or even shorter in small talk: *bien remis ?*).

Comment: Case 7: "Bonne continuation" if you do not expect to see the person again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will add it, it is definitely a very common phrase.

Comment: Note than in a very formal context, you aren't expected to react at all when someone sneeze (and apologize for it).

Comment: For case 3 and a divorce they can be very fitting as well :)

Answer (score 1):

> when someone is sick: how to show his/her support? to ask if thinks get better ? to wish healing ....

- Prends soin de toi (not formal)
- Je vous souhaite un bon rétablissement (formal)
- Je te souhaite un bon rétablissement (less formal but a little bit nevertheless)
- You can say a lot of things actually, I don't think there are strict formulations. "J'espère que tu t'en remettra vite !", "Guéris bien !", etc.

> when someone wants to go to/return from the gym

There is no special formulations. What is your context?

- "Amuse-toi bien à la salle." (something like "enjoy your sport")
- "Bon sport !" (have a nice sport)
- etc.

> someone gets maried/divorce

For the mariage:

- Félicitations !
- Félicitations pour votre mariage (formal)
- Félicitations pour ton mariage (less formal)
- Tous mes vœux de bonnheur ! (I wouldn't say it in formal contexts)

For the divorce:

- Je suis désolé d'apprendre la nouvelle.
- Je suis triste d'apprendre que vous (tu) divorcez (divorces).
- Je suis désolé d'apprendre que (vous) tu (avez) as divorcé(e).

Again, there is no strict formulations

> someone gives birth

- Félicitations !
- Félicitations pour le nouveau-né.
- Je suis heureux d'apprendre cette nouvelle.

> what to say when someone died

- Toute mes condoléances.
- Cette nouvelle m'attriste, toute mes condoléances.

> someone sneezed

- À tes souhaits (then, he'll answer "thank you")
- À vos souhaits (then, he'll answer "thank you")

> when someone will move to another place (last day in a job/neighborhood/city...)

- Bon voyage ! (Safe trip!, Have a nice trip!)
- Bonne continuation. (Good luck, good continuation)

There is a lot of formulations that have not been mentionned and you can just create some.